# Temperature stable PSU

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator

I need a cheap power source (5V 1A approximately) that is temperature stable to about 20ppm/degC. I note that voltage references with this kind of stability are cheap. However, is it possible to use this to create a fairly basic but adequate PSU meeting those specs?

The load it will drive is purely resistive, if that matters

Comment: Just add a beefy buffer to a voltage reference.

Comment: I wonder how practical an ovenized system might be for something like this. You'd be lowering the output capability due to the elevated ambient temperature, but if you're able to keep the temperature constant, the tempco stops mattering so much. As long as you're careful about Rthj-a of your output transistors, anyway. Are you talking about a linear supply or a switching one? I'd assume anything that sensitive to drift would be sensitive to noise, so probably linear, but you don't specify.

Comment: @Hearth This is already in an oven, but one which changes in temperature from 0-85degC

Comment: @DirkBruere If you can keep the temperature-sensitive stuff at 90 °C as the outside temperature varies, you could cancel out any thermal changes.... but that's impractically hot for an oven-stabilized system. Go with some of the other answers; your 20 ppm/K spec isn't *that* hard to achieve by other means, as they explain. Hard, but not extremely hard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *However, is it possible to use this to create a fairly basic but
> adequate PSU meeting those specs?*

If you want 20 ppm/°C then I would go for a voltage reference that is certainly under 10 ppm/°C and probably something more like 4 ppm/°C.

But, to make it work, you need an op-amp to "close the loop" that has awesome offset voltage (and awesome drift) and, large open-loop gain. Again, you can get such a device like the [MCP6L91](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1669466.pdf) or the [AD8615AUJZ](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/609/AD8615_8616_8618-1502461.pdf) to close the loop and, those devices have the bandwidth to cope with rapid load changes whilst ignoring perturbations on their incoming supply.

But you also need good transistors (for the output) and you need to ensure that the whole circuit has no load instabilities.

Resistors are very important and you should choose ones that are either forming a potential divider in a tempco balanced way or ones that are sub 10 ppm/°C.

It's doable within reason.

Comment: 20 ppm/K of 5 V are 100µV/K. Almost 'any' opamp should suffice.

Comment: Just go for the best if it doesn't cost much more. When you add up all the error terms from resistors, dynamic loads (and lack of op-amp BW at those speeds), it makes sense to try and make as many error terms as insignificant as possible. The op-amp is prime candidate for this @tobalt

Comment: Adding on to Andy's comment, if you've ever done a WCA/WCCA (Worst Case Circuit Analysis), you know how fast 0.1% tolerances and 10 uV offsets can add add up to put you out of spec.